# Wordpress REST Create Post of Custom Type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, rest-api

I am using the REST API to create posts.

I am able to create normal posts, but I would like to create posts of custom type.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

I am trying to `POST` to the above URL with data as

```
title: 'Loreum Ipsum',
content: 'Test Post',
post_type: custom_type
```

which doesn't create the post of type `custom_type` instead normal post is created.

---

I tried posting to

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?post_type=custom_post
```

with the data,

```
title: 'Loreum Ipsum',
content: 'Test Post',
```

but still it creates normal post.

---

I also have tried to send the data as

```
title: 'Loreum Ipsum',
content: 'Test Post',
type: custom_type
```

to `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

which also creates normal post.

---

I am using POSTMAN to send the data. What else should I try?

Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: `post_type` is not a valid argument when creating a post. See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/). To use custom post types with the REST API you need to enable support for it, which will create a dedicated endpoint for it. Again, see [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/).

Comment: does your post type specify that it should be exposed in REST when you register it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your post type is shown in the REST API.

```
$args = array(
  //* Use whatever other args you want
  'show_in_rest'          => true,
  'rest_base'             => 'myslug',
  'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
);
register_post_type( 'myslug', $args );
```

The endpoint to create a post would then be `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/myslug`.

Edit:

The above is all that's needed for a custom post type to be available as a REST endpoint using the default WP_REST_Posts_Controller. I initially had the following code, because I think it makes using the REST API easier. However, as pointed out in the comments, it's not needed to answer this question. You can just use the endpoint.

```
function wpse294085_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', PATH_TO . 'my-script.js', [ 'wp-api' ] );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse294085_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Then in my-script.js, just use Backbone.

```
wp.api.loadPromise.done( function() {
  var post = new wp.api.models.Myslug( {
    'id': null,
    'title': 'Example New Post',
    'content': 'YOLO'
  } );
  var xhr = post.save();
});
```

Comment: The point of having a restful API is to not to depend on some specific technology to sue it, otherwise it is not an API,and only the JS interface is.

Comment: ... answer is probably much more correct if you remove the JS related stuff

Comment: Huh? Backbone isn't required to use the REST API. It's just really easy, so why not. The endpoint is still there.

Comment: it is not easy at all to use it from outside of a browser.

Comment: Is the `rest_controller_class` even necessary? I've never needed it myself, only `show_in_rest`

Comment: @NathanJohnson, what do you mean:
The endpoint to create a post would then be http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/myslug.

Do you have an example of how that would look with auth? I am using Node, and am trying to create woocommerce MembershipTeams. I have added the 
'show_in_rest' for the custom post type: wc_memberships_team, but now I am not sure how to create new post of that type. I can fetch with that appended to the end of the url e.g. http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/wc_memberships_team